# Optimizaion(Reduce Complexity). Count Acute, Right and Obtuse triangles from n side lengths

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, time-complexity

**Edit 1: Changed 104 to 10^4 in constraints. Sorry for the mistake.**

**Problem Statement:**
We have N sticks. The size of the ith stick is Ai. We want to know the number of different types of triangles created with each side from a single different stick. Calculate the number of acute triangles, right triangles and obtuse triangles.

**Input Format:**
 The first line contains N. 
 The second line contains N integers. The ith number denotes Ai.

**Constraints:**

```
For full score: 3≤N≤5000
For 40% score: 3≤N≤500
```

**For all testcases**:

```
1≤A[i]≤10^4
A[i]<A[i+1] where 1≤i<N
```

**Output Format**:
 Print 3 integers: the number of acute triangles, right triangles and obtuse triangles, respectively.

**My Solution:**
My code runs in the given time for small n(~500). It will work for large n(~5000) but I get time limit exceeded error on the Online Judge.

**My Code**: I have used C# as the language. I hope to get a solution in the same.

```
using System;

namespace CodeStorm
{
    class CountingTriangles
    {
        public static double square(int x)
        {
            return Math.Pow(x, 2);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            string[] A_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            int[] A = Array.ConvertAll(A_temp, Int32.Parse);

            int acute = 0, right = 0, obtuse = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; i++) 
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < n - 1; j++) 
                {
                    int k = j + 1;
                    while (k < n && A[i] + A[j] > A[k])
                    {
                        if (square(A[i]) + square(A[j]) == square(A[k]))
                        {
                            right++;
                        }
                        else if (square(A[i]) + square(A[j]) > square(A[k]))
                        {
                            acute++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            obtuse++;
                        }
                        k++;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(acute + " " + right + " " + obtuse);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

https://ideone.com/zbQXE9

The above code runs perfectly and find the possible triangles

**Input:**

```
6    
2 3 9 10 12 15
```

**Output:**

```
2 1 4
```

**The possible triangles are:**

Acute triangles
10−12−15, 9−10−12

Right triangle
9−12−15

Obtuse triangles
2−9−10, 3−9−10, 3−10−12, 9−10−15

I want to know a more efficient way to approach the problem so that I can get it executed in the given time limit for n(~5000). 
After I tried to find the complexity, I came up with O(n^3). I am not good with complexities. I might be wrong. I would like a more efficient way for the problem.

Comment: How far away are you from the time limit?

Comment: The code runs for 50% of the test cases ranging from 0.04s to 1.73s (8 test cases). But for the remaining test cases(8 cases) it exceeds the 3s time limit.

Comment: I am sorry. But I require a detailed answer. I am new to competitive programming. I don't know about auxiliary array or caching.

Comment: Might be suitable here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

You can improve the approach in the following manner: first sort all the sticks by their length. After that iterate over each pair of sticks(i.e. double cycle with square complexity). For each pair perform a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find the location in the array of sticks where you switch from acute to right angled triangles(considering the two sticks you've preselected and the third one as base). Then perform another binary to find the location where you switch form right to obtuse triangles. After that you will have to perform yet another binary search to find the position where the third stick is so long that you can not form a valid triangle with it. You will have to handle one more case - if there are no right angle triangles and you switch from acute directly to obtuse(this can be done by adding a single if).

It is important to note that the type of triangle is determined by the angle opposite to the biggest side of the triangle, thus in the above algorithm you should only consider side lengths bigger than the two preselected sticks(which can be done using another binary).

Overall the approach I propose has complexity O(N<sup>2</sup> * log(N)) which is asymptotically better than your algorithm.

Comment: The third stick might not allow a triangle with the two selected before.

Comment: Good point and that would require another binary search, still the same complexity

Comment: I am trying to understand what you want to say but it is hard for me. I will take some time and try harder and will come back to you if I have any doubt. Thank you.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Sir, I am not able to come up with a solution. It would be really helpful if you can share some code or algorithm for the mentioned problem. Thank you.

Comment: I've already included link to the binary search algorithm explained. There really is not much more to the solution I propose. I don't think including the code will do you any good.  Please try to understand the algorithm and work on it on your own. This way you will understand it much better

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I really appreciate your concern. I'll try harder to understand the algorithm. Thank You.

Comment: Thank You so much @IvayloStrandjev. I was able to optimize my code to some extent. I am able to complete 8 out of 12 test cases now within the time limit(1.05s for the case for n=3000). But the remaining 4 cases are still giving me a TLE error. For these 4 cases n = 5000, and my code exceeds the 3sec time limit. Is there any way by which I can know how much time is my code taking? Thanks a lot. And here is the code if you want to see it -> [CODE](http://ideone.com/hwwQQF)

Comment: @AmanAhuja please do not accept my answer if it does not work for you.  Upvote is enough if it helped you.  Accept would mean that this approach solved your problem while you are still searching for a better solution. I will try to think of an asymptomatically better approach but I don't know one right now

Answer (score 2):

I do not see a method to reduce complexity at the moment but you can make some speedups about your code.

- calculate the squares of the `A[i]` upfront instead of calculating them over and over again
- if the lengths are sorted as in your example (if not sort them) you can exit the while loop as soon as the condition `A[i] + A[j] > A[k]` is violated the first time
- store the values for `n - 1` and `n -2` in variables instead of calculating them over and over again (may already be optimized by the compiler)
- do not calculate `square(A[i]) + square(A[j])` twice, store the result in a variable.
- change order of checking-conditions. right angled triangles are the less likely. Always check the most common case first.
- using `a * a` is likely to be much faster for integer values than `square(a)`

Here you can see what I mean (you still have to implement the TODO parts)

```
using System;

namespace CodeStorm
{
    class CountingTriangles
    {
        public static double square(int x)
        {
            return Math.Pow(x, 2);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            string[] A_temp = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            int[] A = Array.ConvertAll(A_temp, Int32.Parse);
            // TODO: sort A[]  (if it is not already always sorted)
            // TODO: create an array of the square-valuee
            int[] Asquares = ....
            int n_m_2= n-2;
            int n_m_1= n-1;

            int acute = 0, right = 0, obtuse = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n_m_2; i++) 
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < n_m_1; j++) 
                {
                    int k = j + 1;
                    int AiPlusAj = A[i] + A[j];
                    while (k < n )
                    {
                        if(AiPlusAj <= A[k]){
                          break; 
                        }

                        int squareSum= Asquares[i] + Asquares[j];
                        else if (squareSum > Asquares[k])
                        {
                            acute++;
                        }
                        else if (squareSum < Asquares[k])
                        {
                            obtuse++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            right++;
                        }
                        k++;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(acute + " " + right + " " + obtuse);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did all the changes. The result improved for the first 8 test cases (0.04s to 0.09s) earlier it was 0.04s to 1.73s. But it still exceeds the 3s timer on the remaining 8 cases. Thank you for the changes. They will help me in future.

Comment: I added code and an extra optimization point. But I think reducing the complexity like **Ivaylo Strandjev** wrote in his answer will speed things up even more (at lest for big values of n)

Comment: I am new to algorithms. I am unable to understand what he is saying. Not so good with binary searches. Maybe I am not understanding what he wants to tell.

Comment: **binary search** is simply search in a sorted array in O(log n) time. It's not so hard to understand e.g. watch a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQhciTuD3E8

Answer (score 2):

Just a small hint: Math.Pow() is rather slow for computing squares. You should modify your method square:

```
public static double square(int x)
{
    return x * x;
}
```

Comment: With `A[i]≤104`, why use `double`?

Comment: @greybeard Yes, you are right. No need for a double here.

Comment: It is 10^4. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @AmanAhuja : Diligent of you to improve the question proper. 10^8 is well within the range of `int` claimed by Microsoft (while 10^10 isn't: go figure).

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved in time `O(N²)`. If necessary, sort the sizes increasingly.

Let the sides of a triangle be `a = A[k]`, `b = A[j]`, `c = A[i]`, with `a < b < c` to ensure uniqueness. For a triangle to be possible, the constraint `c < a + b` must be verified. Then a triangle is classed as acute/right/obtuse based on the relation `c² >< a² + b²`.

Let us choose `c = A[i]`. Then in the plane `(a, b)` (`a` horizontal), the constraints `a < b < c` define the domain of the possible triangles, itself a triangle (green in the picture), which is traversed by the circle of equation `c² = a² + b²`.

[image]

Proceed as follows:

- start from `b = c = A[j] = A[i]` and loop

  - for a given value of `b`, find the largest `a`'s that verify `a + b < c` (let `a = A[k0]`), `a² + b² < c²` (`a = A[k1]`) and `a < b` (`a = A[k2] = A[j]`). These correspond to intersections of an horizontal with the oblique sides and the circular arc.
  - get the next smaller `b = A[j]` and update the the three `a`'s. (You are "cross-hatching" the two regions in the triangle.)
- until you reach `b < c / 2`.

The numbers of triangles of each type are given by the three sums of the numbers of solutions, i.e. respectively `k1 - k0`, `1` if equality is met, and `k2 - k1`.

The cost of the loop is linear, `O(N)`, by monotonicity (when you decrease `b`, you increase/decrease the `k`'s always in the same direction).

Repeating for all `c = A[i]`, we get the claimed `O(N²)`.

Comment: Note that the above description isn't quite rigorous regarding strict/non-strict inequalities. This implementation detail doesn't change the conclusion.

Comment: An interesting approach indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Two things that will almost certainly improve things:

1. Make the squaring faster, use `x * x` rather than casting to double, and calling `Pow`.
2. Calculate the square once per `i`, once per `j` and once per `k`.

Things that may improve things, and may make them worse (profile):

1. Work on pre-sorted data.
2. Calculate the threshold for the final size (square-root of the other two squares) and just compare with that in the loop.
3. Have a different loop for when the two squares don't sum to a whole-number square (no value can match the right-angle case).

Answer (score 0):

We can just start the search for the third stick where we left off, for a complexity of **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**. Python (sorry; should be comprehensible though), **now tested**:

```
acute = 0
right = 0
obtuse = 0
a = sorted(a)  # copy and convert to a list
a.append(2 * a[-1])  # add a sentinel equal to twice the max
for i in range(len(a) - 3):  # exclude the sentinel
    if a[i] <= 0:
        continue
    ka = i + 2
    kr = i + 2
    ko = i + 2
    for j in range(i + 1, len(a) - 2):  # i < j, exclude the sentinel
        ka = max(ka, j + 1)
        while a[i] ** 2 + a[j] ** 2 > a[ka] ** 2:
            ka += 1
        acute += ka - (j + 1)
        kr = max(kr, ka)
        while a[i] ** 2 + a[j] ** 2 == a[kr] ** 2:
            kr += 1
        right += kr - ka
        ko = max(ko, kr)
        while a[i] + a[j] > a[ko]:
            ko += 1
        obtuse += ko - kr
```